# Unpickling error when running fairseq on AML using multiple GPUs

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run fairseq translation task on AML using 4 GPUs (P100)and it fails with the following error:

> -- Process 2 terminated with the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/azureml-envs/azureml_8ef3d311fd9072540e3352d9621cca49/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fairseq/distributed_utils.py",
>   line 174, in all_gather_list
>       result.append(pickle.loads(bytes(out_buffer[2 : size + 2].tolist())))
>   _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xad'.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/azureml-envs/azureml_8ef3d311fd9072540e3352d9621cca49/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
>   line 19, in _wrap
>       fn(i, *args)   File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/nlx-ml-neuralrewrite/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/mounts/workspacefilestore/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/train.py",
>   line 272, in distributed_main
>       main(args, init_distributed=True)   File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/nlx-ml-neuralrewrite/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/mounts/workspacefilestore/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/train.py",
>   line 82, in main
>       train(args, trainer, task, epoch_itr)   File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/nlx-ml-neuralrewrite/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/mounts/workspacefilestore/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/train.py",
>   line 123, in train
>       log_output = trainer.train_step(samples)   File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8ef3d311fd9072540e3352d9621cca49/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fairseq/trainer.py",
>   line 305, in train_step
>       [logging_outputs, sample_sizes, ooms, self._prev_grad_norm],   File
>   "/azureml-envs/azureml_8ef3d311fd9072540e3352d9621cca49/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fairseq/distributed_utils.py",
>   line 178, in all_gather_list
>       'Unable to unpickle data from other workers. all_gather_list requires all ' Exception: Unable to unpickle data from other workers.
>   all_gather_list requires all workers to enter the function together,
>   so this error usually indicates that the workers have fallen out of
>   sync somehow. Workers can fall out of sync if one of them runs out of
>   memory, or if there are other conditions in your training script that
>   can cause one worker to finish an epoch while other workers are still
>   iterating over their portions of the data.
>
> 2019-09-18
>   17:28:44,727|azureml.WorkerPool|DEBUG|[STOP]
>
> Error occurred: User program failed with Exception:
>
> -- Process 2 terminated with the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/azureml-envs/azureml_8ef3d311fd9072540e3352d9621cca49/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fairseq/distributed_utils.py",
>   line 174, in all_gather_list
>       result.append(pickle.loads(bytes(out_buffer[2 : size + 2].tolist())))
>   _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xad'.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/azureml-envs/azureml_8ef3d311fd9072540e3352d9621cca49/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
>   line 19, in _wrap
>       fn(i, *args)   File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/nlx-ml-neuralrewrite/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/mounts/workspacefilestore/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/train.py",
>   line 272, in distributed_main
>       main(args, init_distributed=True)   File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/nlx-ml-neuralrewrite/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/mounts/workspacefilestore/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/train.py",
>   line 82, in main
>       train(args, trainer, task, epoch_itr)   File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/nlx-ml-neuralrewrite/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/mounts/workspacefilestore/azureml/pytorch-fairseq_1568826205_6846ecb6/train.py",
>   line 123, in train
>       log_output = trainer.train_step(samples)   File "/azureml-envs/azureml_8ef3d311fd9072540e3352d9621cca49/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fairseq/trainer.py",
>   line 305, in train_step
>       [logging_outputs, sample_sizes, ooms, self._prev_grad_norm],   File
>   "/azureml-envs/azureml_8ef3d311fd9072540e3352d9621cca49/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fairseq/distributed_utils.py",
>   line 178, in all_gather_list
>       'Unable to unpickle data from other workers. all_gather_list requires all ' Exception: Unable to unpickle data from other workers.
>   all_gather_list requires all workers to enter the function together,
>   so this error usually indicates that the workers have fallen out of
>   sync somehow. Workers can fall out of sync if one of them runs out of
>   memory, or if there are other conditions in your training script that
>   can cause one worker to finish an epoch while other workers are still
>   iterating over their portions of the data.

The same code with same param runs fine on a single local GPU. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you show the exact call that is failing?

Comment: In particular, which file is being unpickled and where is it coming from?

Comment: It doesn't say which file was being unpickled.

I am just creating an estimator as:
`est = PyTorch(source_directory='./fairseq',
                   script_params=script_params,
                   compute_target=compute_target,
                   entry_script='train.py',
                   pip_packages=['fairseq', 'tensorboardX'],
                   use_gpu=True)
`
and then submitting a run with it. It loads the data, creates the model and then fails after a few minutes with the above error

Comment: Weirdly, it seems to run fine in a different workspace with V100 GPUs